# data.table::merge How to avoid encoding warnings with merge?

Tags: r, encoding, merge, data.table

Using `merge` of `data.table` I get an encoding warnings.  My process is as fellow:

1. I am creating a first data.table
2. I update this data.table using `merge`.

But I when I call `merge` I get this warning :

```
Please ensure that character columns have identical encodings for joins.
```

How can I tell data.table of the encoding used? I know I can remove warning using `suppressWarnings` but I prefer to fix this since in a clean way.

This reproduces the warining:

```
library(data.table)
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
dt = data.table(text=c('é','à','s'),
                title='agstudy',hrefs='a')
setkeyv(dt,names(dt))  
dt.new = data.table(text=c('é','à','h','a'),
                    hrefs=c(rep('a',2),rep('aa',2)),
                    title=c(rep('agstudy',2),rep('new',2)))
setkeyv(dt.new,names(dt.new))
merge(dt.new,dt,all=TRUE)

Warning messages:
1: In `[.data.table`(y, xkey, nomatch = ifelse(all.x, NA, 0), allow.cartesian = allow.cartesian) :
  Encoding of character column 'text' in X is different from column 'text' in Y 
  in join X[Y]. Joins are not implemented yet for non-identical character encodings 
  and therefore likely to contain unexpected results for those entries. 
  Please ensure that character columns have identical encodings for joins.
```

**EDIT** add some session information:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
[1] data.table_1.8.11
```

**EDIT2** add some context

My data.table is created after some scraping where I set the encoding to `UTF-8` using htmlParse(...,encoding='UTF-8') then I am creating the data.table using the scraped text.

Comment: I have no warning. What give you `Encoding(dt$text)`? I have `"unknown" "latin1"  "latin1"`, my script is saved in UTF-8 with RStudio.

Comment: I'm sorry, I ran your code but I don't get any warning. edit: I have the same characteristics as Victorp

Comment: Ok I used data.table_1.8.10. With data.table_1.8.11 I have the warning.

Comment: data.table version 1.8.10, R version 3.1.0

Comment: I can also reproduce this. The problem seems to be that `Encoding(dt[[1]])` is `[1] "latin1"  "latin1"  "unknown"`, i.e., there are mixed encodings. But according to the documentation: "ASCII strings will never be marked with a declared encoding, since their representation is the same in all supported encodings." So, I don't see a way to avoid the warning.

Comment: @Roland thanks. But I don't get the same result with `Encoding(dt[[1]])` is `[1] "unknown" "unknown" "unknown"`

Comment: That is surprising. `Encoding("é")` gives `[1] "latin1"` on my Win7 system.

Comment: mee too I get `latin1`! Amazing! I will check if my data.table version is not the dev version.

Comment: @Arun I tried using `dt[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, enc2utf8)]` and it doesn't help since ascii characters stay "unknown". The warning apparently cannot be avoided if you have non-ascii characters.

Comment: @Arun Aha. I took the liberty to put that into an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The warning results from a mixture of encodings in your character vectors. The ascii characters have encoding "unknown", but others are probably "latin1".

Use this to convert all encodings to unknown:

```
dt[, names(dt) := lapply(.SD, function(x) {if (is.character(x)) Encoding(x) <- "unknown"; x})]
```

If you do the same for the second DT, you avoid the warning.

Note that you are using a development version. The behaviour could change soon.

Comment: Hm, not quite. It shouldn't happen when the characters are `ascii`. At least that's what I remember. If non-ascii encodings are present but have both "proper" and "unknown" encodings, then there should a warning..

Comment: @Arun No, run the code from the question. All non-ascii characters have the same encoding (latin1 on windows). Only ascii characters have a different encoding (unknown).

Comment: Maybe there shouldn't be warnings (I agree). But there are warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The encoding issues are fixed in v1.9.7 (current devel). See [ReleaseNotes, Bug Fixes #23](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/ReleaseNotes.md). This should work as intended without any warnings or need for conversion of encodings. Please report back if it doesn't.

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.7+
dt = data.table(text=c('é','à','s'), title='agstudy',hrefs='a')
dt.new = data.table(text=c('é','à','h','a'), hrefs=c(rep('a',2),rep('aa',2)), title=c(rep('agstudy',2),rep('new',2)))

merge(dt.new, dt, all=TRUE)
#    text hrefs   title
# 1:    a    aa     new
# 2:    h    aa     new
# 3:    s     a agstudy
# 4:    à     a agstudy
# 5:    é     a agstudy

merge(dt.new, dt, all=TRUE, by=c("text", "title"))
#    text   title hrefs.x hrefs.y
# 1:    a     new      aa      NA
# 2:    h     new      aa      NA
# 3:    s agstudy      NA       a
# 4:    à agstudy       a       a
# 5:    é agstudy       a       a
```